# System.Threading.Timer stops the thread?

Tags: c#, timer

Can a timer stop the thread which is running now by return from callback?

I need a timer which will run some function in a certain time. But this function lasts more than timer tick.

```
_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Process), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

and callback:

```
public void Process(Object stateinfo)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
    //run once a day between 2 and 5 am
    if (LastCheckDateTime == DateTime.Today || dt.ToString("HHmm").CompareTo("0200") < 0 || dt.ToString("HHmm").CompareTo("0500") > 0)
    return;

    try
    {
       LastCheckDateTime = DateTime.Today;
       foo(); //lasts 4 hours
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       LastCheckDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
       //if some problems, Process must start again until 5 am
    }
}
```

This code started today at 2:56am but didn't finish, Is this because at 5am it was still running?

And how to fix this?

Comment: You want to abort the operation if lasts more than a timer tick?

Comment: No, this ok, I just want it to start at 2 and restart until 5 if something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by *"until 5"*? if it takes more than 3 hours then restart it?

Comment: Why not just use a simple mechanism such as populate a session variable with the time when the method starts and clear the variable when it stops... then in your timer if the session var is populated don't run more than say 3 hrs old stop it and retry... or something similar.

Comment: No, I don't want to restart it if it takes more than 3 hours, only if it catch an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, you used the best Timer in my mind (System.Threading).
There isn't problem to re-execute the same method even if previous call isn't finished. The previous instance isn't killed.
You just have to manage the reentrancy, but the way you did it prevents problems (your timer fires each hour so there is no threading problem between the line which checks 'LastCheckDateTime' and the line which change its value).

I tried the following which works well: the event is fired every second but the "Process" starts by a 3s wait.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(Process), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    private void Process(object state)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Debug.WriteLine("dt=" + dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + " Now=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));

    }

}
```

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, I just want to asc if this good practice to use Sleep? There are another threads in programm which use Sleeps too, but they implemented via Thread: new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Process));

Comment: and I still don't understand why foo() stopped without any Exception, what could prevent it? Timer  couldn't do this?

Comment: Indeed, you are right, Thread.Sleep() isn't a good practice at all. But it is really usefull to me for test purposes. For "real code", this is always possible, in my mind, to handle delays with timers or asynchronous code (BackgroundWorker, events, IAsyncResult, Task<>).